# Why did the placeholder error occurred when executing continuous query in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Why did the placeholder error occurred when executing continuous query in Apache IoTDB?
I have a question for using continuous query in Apache IoTDB. I create a continuous query using command like the following: `CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cancq_1 RESAMPLE EVERY 10s   BEGIN  SELECT max_value(BMSCellMaxVol),max_value(HDop),max_value(EPBSysBrkLghtsReqd) INTO root.ota.misc.ep.::(::) FROM root.v.ep.m.* GROUP BY(1s) align by device  END` ,
but an error occurred: `Msg: 305: select into: placeholders can only be used in raw time series data queries`. I checked and was able to execute the detail placeholders in the `SELECT BMSCellMaxVol,HDop,EPBSysBrkLghtsReqd INTO root.ota.misc.ep.::(::)` statement, so I want to know why did the placeholder error appeared?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the detailed variable placeholders of Apache IoTDB cannot be used in aggregation query and can only describe the correspondence between time series. However, you can use device-level placeholders in this case. You can change your continuous query statement to:
`CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cancq_1 RESAMPLE EVERY 10s   BEGIN  SELECT max_value(BMSCellMaxVol),max_value(HDop),max_value(EPBSysBrkLghtsReqd)  INTO root.ota.misc.ep.::(BMSCellMaxVol_MAX_VALUE, HDop_MAX_VALUE, EPBSysBrkLghtsReqd_MAX_VALUE)  FROM root.v.ep.m.* GROUP BY(1s) align by device  END`.